# OpenGL, GLFW, GLAD. glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600) throwing memory errors

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I've recently started following [these](https://learnopengl.com/) OpenGL tutorials. I've had no trouble up until the **Hello Window** tutorial, where the function `gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)` returns false. This results in the errors:

`Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in openGL_001.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.`

and

`Unhandled exception at 0x7281C1ED in openGL_001.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.`

being thrown when the function `glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600)` is called (see code below). I know that the *GLAD* files are the problem as the code contains an if statement (see code below), checking to see if *GLAD* has successfully handled OpenGL's function pointers. I have tried to get it working using the following *GLAD* [configurations](http://glad.dav1d.de/):

Language: C/C++, Specification: OpenGl

- API gl: v.3.0, Profile: Core
- API gl: v.3.3, Profile: Core
- API gl: v.4.4, Profile: Core
- API gl: v.4.6, Profile: Core

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad\glad.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);

int main() {
glfwInit();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Learn OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
if (window = NULL) {
    std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
    std::cout << "Failed to initialise GLAD" << std::endl;
}

glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

//render loop
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
```

}

```
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
```

}

Relevant (hopefully) system information:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2015 Community
- OpenGL 4.4 (GTX 960)

Thanks in advance for any help. If you need anymore info fire away. (Please note that I will not be able to reply within the first 2 hours after this question has been posted.)

Comment: `if (window = NULL) {` This assigns, it does not compare.

Comment: Compiling at a high warning level (`/W4`) will give you a warning when there is an assignment in an `if` statement.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo thanks. It's been one of those days.

Comment: Cheers for the tip @1201ProgramAlarm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Typo in `if` statement. Missing one of the two `=`.